# Standard method for caching data in Android?

Tags: android, caching

I'm a bit confused about how to cache data in Android. I've seen many people implementing their own cache (eg, in [droidfu](https://github.com/kaeppler/droid-fu/tree/master/src/main/java/com/github/droidfu/cachefu) project), but Android seems to have its own caching system with [ResponseCache](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/net/ResponseCache.html).

Is there any reason for not using Android cache?

What's the standard way to cache URLConnection response (text, data, json...), and where can I found examples?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

- You have no control over the size of the cache or when objects get cleared (to my knowledge)
- You cannot set the cache to the SD card

For small web-service requests the `ResponseCache` will suffice, and is the standard way of caching the raw response. It is only really when dealing with larger objects that you will need your own cache.

Alternatively you could

- Serialize the data and save it to a local file
- For basic data you could save it in `SharedPreferences` if it is long-lived

Comment: ResponseCache is added in api level 14,is there any alternative for earlier versions?